# Sylius: how to render a preview of Images on an entity properly using SyliusResourceBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a Custom-Entity that is registered as Sylius-Resource. This entity can have a list of images. For my usecase i followed instructions on the [Docs](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/cookbook/images/images-on-entity.html).

I use a subclass of ImageType in order to provide the Upload-Image-Form:

ArtistImageType:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ImageType;

class ArtistImageType extends ImageType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'artist_image';
    }
}
```

This is how I reuse this ArtistImageType in my FormType:

```
final class ArtistType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
            ])
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => '',
            ])

            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ArtistImageType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => 'app.images',
            ])
```

And the form.html.twig:

```
<div class="ui two column stackable grid">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
            <h4 class="ui dividing header">{{ 'sylius.ui.general_info'|trans }}</h4>
            <div class="two fields">
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            </div>

            {{ form_row(form.images) }}

        </div>
        <div class="ui segment">
            {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
            {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm wondering how i could display the images that was already uploaded in an existing Entity similar to the Product-Form, where existing images are displayed next to the "choose file"-button?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

But it still gets rendered without any Preview. Apparently some further customization is necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After reading Sylius code I can answer myself:

**1. ArtistType::buildForm()**

We need to add the attribute `entry_options` to pass the Artist-Entity to the ImageType:

```
        ->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ArtistImageType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'entry_options' => ['artist' => $options['data']],
            'label' => 'app.images',
```

**2. ArtistImageType**

Then we made ArtistImageType fit to handle this attribute properly:

```
class ArtistImageType extends ImageType
{

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $view->vars['artist'] = $options['artist'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefined('artist');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('artist', Artist::class);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'artist_image';
    }
}
```

Consider the `getBlockPrefix`-method.

**3. Form-Theme:**

Create a Form-Theme for the images-section:

```
{% extends '@SyliusUi/Form/imagesTheme.html.twig' %}

{% block artist_image_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="ui upload box segment">
            {{ form_row(form.type) }}
            <label for="{{ form.file.vars.id }}" class="ui icon labeled button"><i class="cloud upload icon"></i> {{ 'sylius.ui.choose_file'|trans }}</label>
            {% if form.vars.value.path|default(null) is not null %}
                <img class="ui small bordered image" src="{{ form.vars.value.path|imagine_filter('sylius_small') }}" alt="{{ form.vars.value.type }}" />
            {% endif %}
            <div class="ui hidden element">
                {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
            </div>
            <div class="ui element">
                {{- form_errors(form.file) -}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Consider the block name `artist_image_widget`. It is the Link between Twig and getBlockPrefix-Function of the ImageType-implementation.

**4. I've put the whole image-section stuff in a separate file:**

`_media.html.twig`:

```
{% form_theme form '@AppBundle/Form/imagesTheme.html.twig' %}

<div class="ui" >
    <h3 class="ui dividing header">{{ 'sylius.ui.media'|trans }}</h3>
    <br>
    {{ form_row(form.images, {'label': false}) }}

</div>
```

The final form:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="ui segment">
        <h4 class="ui dividing header">{{ 'sylius.ui.general_info'|trans }}</h4>
        <div class="two fields">
            {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        </div>

        {% include 'AppBundle:Admin:_media.html.twig' %}

    </div>
    <div class="ui segment">
        {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
        {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess that 3.Form-Theme posted by @itinance is really what fixes it (by copying widget content instead of form_row(form.images..) i've also manages to make it work). But sadly i couldnt make it work with extending '@SyliusUi/Form/imagesTheme.html.twig', even when getBlockPrefix return matching prefix for this prefix